# Notificaciones no llegan al dispositivo

Tags: php, ios, swift, iphone

Que tal, tengo un problema, intento enviar notificaciones desde php hacia ios, ya hice todos los pasos y probándolo con un programa APN Tester si llegan todo bien, cuando intento enviar desde PHP me sale que se envió correctamente pero no llegan al iPhone, que puede ser?

Este es el código que uso:

```
<?php
// Nuestro token
$deviceToken = '​el token del dispositivo';

// El password del fichero .pem
$passphrase = 'la password 123';

// El mensaje push
$message = '¡Mi primer mensaje Push!';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
//Especificamos la ruta al certificado .pem que hemos creado
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'archivo.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Abrimos conexión con APNS
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
exit("Error de conexión: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

echo 'Conectado al APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Creamos el payload
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 35
);

// Lo codificamos a json
$payload = json_encode($body);
// echo $deviceToken;
// Construimos el mensaje binario
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*',sprintf('%u', CRC32($deviceToken))) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Lo enviamos
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result) {
echo 'Mensaje no enviado' . PHP_EOL;
} else { 
echo 'Mensaje enviado correctamente' . PHP_EOL;
}

// cerramos la conexión
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Generaste todos los certificados y llaves para produccion? Asegurate de ver si provisioning profile permite el uso de notificaciones. Puedo creer que su problema es de certificados y configuracion

Answer (score 1):

Debes revisar que el certificado .pem sea correcto, en este caso de sandbox y no de distribución, también debes revisar que el identificador asociado al provisioning profile permita notificaciones Push, en este ejemplo están desactivadas:

[image: Ejemplo de identificador sin notificaciones Push activas]

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que ver que tus certificados sean correctos, también puedes probar si están correctamente configuradas las notificaciones en tu dispositivo con herramientas como:
APN Tester
https://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12
si con tu certificado, llegan las push en el tester, quiere decir que tienes un problema con php, puede ser tu device token o que tus certificados no sean los correctos, puedes verificar si pruebas con plataformas como firebase que tus certificados coincidan con lo anterior y probar mandar push, saludos!